# How to do a simple drawing app in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drawing

I am trying to do a simple drawing app in Flash Professional CC. By simple, I just mean something that allows the user to click down and draw and mouseup- stop drawing.

I've been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXdphAAH1mQ

However, on the line:

```
... _root._xmouse, _root._ymouse
```

I get an error which says that it's undefined... I tried mouseX as well, which also didn't work.

I assume it's because I'm using Professional CC so it may be a different version of AS. Does anyone have any tips on how I can get a drawing app working on Prof CC?

Comment: _root is a property of AS2, try using stage.mouseX and stage.mouseY

Comment: First, drop Flash CC and use pure AS3 in [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org). Use flash only to create some assets.

Answer (score 0):

`_root._xmouse, _root._ymouse` It's an AS2. As you could see in Tutorial, he also creates AS2 project. I'm not sure, that you can create AS2 project in Flach CC. As far as I can see, there is no option to create ActionScript 2. Here is [AS3 Drawing App tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-basic-drawing-application-in-flash--active-1627);